# S3 Download to FileStream in Promise?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to do this:

```
function getObjectStream(keyFile) {
    return new Promise(function(success, reject) {
        let stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: aws_exports.imageBucket, Key: keyFile })
            .createReadStream()
            .on('end', function () {
            console.log("sucesfully downloaded");
            success(stream);
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Which is basically downloading an object from S3, turning it into a readstream, then returning success or fail on the creation of that readstream.

The problem is that `.on('end', function ()` doesn't really get called on succesfull creation of the stream. Neither does 'open' for the event.

How could I implement this kind of logic in a promise?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by reading it as a stream? It will provide poor performance for large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong here is `.on('end', function ())` instead of `.on('close', function ())`.

But why even do it this way? `aws-sdk` provides a [`.promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html), and you could simply do

```
s3.getObject(params).promise().then(...).catch(...)
```

or make use of async/await.

Assuming you need it in stream only, try something like this:

```
function getObjectAndWriteToFile(keyFile) {
  return new Promise(function(success, reject) {
    const destPath = `/tmp/${path.basename(key)}`
    s3.getObject({ Bucket: aws_exports.imageBucket, Key: keyFile })
      .createReadStream()
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destPath))
      .on('close', function () {
          console.log("sucesfully downloaded");
          resolve(destPath)
      })
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

I would suggest reading this [thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1436).